# PKCS12 Client Certificate in C# with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I need to use a certificate client .pkcs12 for a windows phone application.
I can't use X509Certificate class because PKCS12 is not allowed. So I download the BouncyCastle class and make this

```
try
{
    FileStream Cert = new FileStream 
                           ("certificate.pkcs12",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    char[] password = new char[] { 'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d' };
    Pkcs12Store certificate = new Pkcs12Store(Cert,password);
}     
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
```

I obtain this exception:

```
 {System.TypeInitializationException: 
   The type initializer for 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PkcsObjectIdentifiers' 
    threw an exception. --->
     System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
```

Comment: What does the InnerException say?

Comment: Inner exception:
+  InnerException {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerObjectIdentifier..ctor(String identifier)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PkcsObjectIdentifiers..cctor()} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

Comment: Either your project isn't referencing system, or this dll is for the wrong framework version and may need to be compiled, of perhaps it is a generic dll that uses/references something that the windows phone does not support.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "downloaded the BouncyCastle class". The shipped binaries for BC are not compiled for Windows Phone. As of the 1.7 release, you would need to build the library yourself (or just include the code in your project) targeted to the appropriate platform. See e.g. http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html

Comment: You were right the dll was for the wrong framework finally I tried with the nuget gallery "WinRTBouncyCastle 0.1.0" ( http://nuget.org/packages/WinRTBouncyCastle/ ) and now it run successfully. Thank you very much everybody for your help!!

Comment: Great. For future readers, we're intending to make an official Portable Class Library version available (also via NuGet) for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a FileNotFoundException i has probably nothing to do with BouncyCastle. Are you sure that you have the file in the right place and that you are using the right filename?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm sure that I have the file in the right place and that i am using the right name because I have no error on the line FileStream. The exception error appears on the Pkcs12Store instruction.